# Matlab : sum of functions by Iteration?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a code to produce sum of functions through iteration.

```
syms c p
for j=1:10
    func=@(c,p)(j+1-c-p*j)^2
    yfunc=@(c,p)(yfunc(c,p)+func(c,p))
end
```

At the end of the day, 'yfunc' will have 10 different terms from 'func's.
But this code doesn't work.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
syms c p;
yfunc = symfun(0,[c,p]);
for j=1:10
    func= symfun((j+1-c-p*j)^2,[c,p]);
    yfunc=yfunc+func;
end
```

This results in:

```
yfunc(c, p) =

(c + p - 2)^2 + (c + 2*p - 3)^2 + (c + 3*p - 4)^2 + (c + 4*p - 5)^2 + (c + 5*p - 6)^2 + (c + 6*p - 7)^2 + (c + 7*p - 8)^2 + (c + 8*p - 9)^2 + (c + 9*p - 10)^2 + (c + 10*p - 11)^2
```

Comment: Thanks! But My matlab version is old, I don't have 'symfun'. I guess I should try to down that function.